# How to get weather info by Latitude & longitude from "http://api.wunderground.com"

Tags: java, android, xml, nodes, weather

I can't get weather information from http://api.wunderground.com by set latitude and longitude in this way:

String urlString = "http://api.wunderground.com/auto/wui/geo/GeoLookupXML/index.xml?query="+lat+","+lng;

I don't know how to to keep what I need from that xml. How I can do this? There is an example?

I want just to know how to convert this url to a "Document" to read from it the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

They have updated there system.  I would use the JSON API.

http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/documentation.html#radar

Using

http://api.wunderground.com/api/YOURAPIKEY/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/CA/San_Francisco.json